# RabbitMQ changing log directory

Tags: logging, rabbitmq

How can I change log directory for RabbitMQ?
On Windows, I set a system variable RABBITMQ_BASE which has a path to `D:\RabbitMQ`.

But when I started bat file and server and the service was running, logs were saved here `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log`. I did everything with an administrator account, so how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, set RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE and RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE. WIth these variables it is working